# How to get phone number from users 2FA using Graph SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a MS Graph SDK v4.7

I need to get users phone number that is used in 2FA against ADB2C.

In documentation, I can see:

`graphClient.user[id].Authentication.PhoneMethods...`

but there is no such property in my version of the Graph SDK. All there is is:

`graphClient.user[id].Authentication.Methods...`

but that one doesn't contain anything related to phones.

Am I missing something?
How to get the phone number used for 2FA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to update at least to SDK v4.35 which is the first version that contains authentication phone methods.

[AuthenticationRequestBuilder](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/4.35.0/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/requests/AuthenticationRequestBuilder.cs)

SDK v4.7 doesn't have a request builder for phone methods and related model.